# How to save escape sequences to a file in python without double backslashes?

Tags: python, string, file-handling

I want to save some mathjax code to a .txt file in python.

```
x = "$\infty$"
with open("sampletext.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.write(x)
```

Works exactly as expected

*sampletext.txt*

```
$\infty$
```

**However when i try to save the escape sequence in a list**

```
x = ["$\infty$"]
with open("sampletext.txt", "a+") as f  :
    f.write(str(x))
```

*sampletext.txt*

```
['$\\infty$']
```

**How do i remove the double backslash in the latter and save it as `['$\infty$']` ?**

Comment: You write the representation of the list and that is just what it looks like. You would have to do something like `f.write(f'[{x[0]}]')` (untested). On the other hand if you really want to store lists you might want to think about saving the data as JSON.

Comment: @Matthias i tried json.dump() and it converts it to double slashes too :/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you:

```
x = [r"$\infty$"]
with open("sampletext.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.write(''.join(x))
```

Flag "r" (raw) can be use to save string with special symbols like "\"

Or if you don't know how many items in the list:

```
x = ["$\infty$"]
with open("sampletext.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.write(f"{''.join(x)}")
```

Comment: the `r` is doing nothing in the second example.  there aren't any escape codes in there to disable escaping for!  this is just doing `f.write(''.join(x))`.  or even:  `for s in x: f.write(s)`

Comment: i want to write ```['$\infty$']```, not ```$\infty$```.
How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x = [r"$\infty$"]
with open("sampletext.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.write(str(x))
```

> The r means that the string is to be treated as a raw string, which means all escape codes will be ignored.

Comment: You left out the `list` part.